# How to get Desktop Location for Windows in Java

Tags: java, desktop

I was wondering how I would get the desktop location in a java program. I looked at some answers and some people said just `System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop` but the thing about that is, not all desktops are in the same location. Mine is under OneDrive but my friend's is under `user.home`. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Do you know the _user-name_ at design-time or can it vary? The location of _desktop_ folder depends on the user's Windows-setup (e.g. using OneDrive, customized location, older Windows-version, etc.). Can give more context/requirements for this ... probably there is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the windows API command for getting the desktop location. Running `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")` on powershell ought to do the trick

Here's an example of how to implement it in java:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String command="powershell -command \"[Environment]::GetFolderPath('\"Desktop\"')\"";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);//I'm printing out the output here. I'm sure you can take it from there for whatever your purpose is?
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Edit** 
 If you actully try it, please let me know the result. I'm curious about the Onedrive desktop case

Comment: It is always better to use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) rather than Runtime.exec:  `Process process = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-command", "[Environment]::GetFolderPath(\"Desktop\")").start();`

Answer (score 0):

This might be work for onedrive case.

```
    String desktopPath;
    
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();

    if (env.containsKey("ONEDRIVE"))
    {
        desktopPath = env.get("ONEDRIVE") + "\\Desktop";
    }
    else
    {
        desktopPath = env.get("USERPROFILE") + "\\Desktop";
    }

    System.out.println(desktopPath);
```